# Rewrite a URL with Flask

Tags: python, url, url-rewriting, flask

Is it possible to rewrite a URL with Flask e.g. if a POST request is received via this route:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def main():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #TODO: rewrite url to something like '/message'
        return render_template('message.html')
    else:
        return render_template('index.html')
```

I'm aware I can use a redirect and setup another route but I prefer to simply modify the url if possible.

Comment: Do you mean you want to change URL info in the POST message you get?

Comment: I was hoping to be able to change the URL that the user sees in the browser bar.  Can that only be done on the clientside e.g. with JS or with a Flask redirect?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you could be interested in redirect behavior

```
from flask import Flask,redirect
```

then use

```
redirect("http://www.example.com", code=302)
```

see: [Redirecting to URL in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14343812/redirecting-to-url-in-flask)

Comment: That induces a new request to the server. Is there a way to actually do what was asked initially ?

Comment: The OP specifically mentioned being aware that they could use rewrite, but asked if they could modify the URL *without* doing a redirect.

Answer (score 0):

You can call your route endpoint functions from another routes:

```
# The “target” route:
@route('/foo')
def foo():
    return render_template(...)

# The rewrited route:
@route('/bar')
def bar():
    return foo()
```

You can even access `g` etc.  This approach can  be also used when the Flask's routing facilities cannot do something that you want to implement.

Answer (score 0):

This is actual solution to this problem (but maybe a dirty hack):

```
def rewrite(url):
    view_func, view_args = app.create_url_adapter(request).match(url)
    return app.view_functions[view_func](**view_args)
```

We invoke the URL dispatcher and call the view function.

Usage:

```
@app.route('/bar')
def the_rewritten_one():
    return rewrite('/foo')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for


app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def home():
    return "hello"

@app.route("/admin"):
def admin():
    return redirect(url_for("#name of function for page you want to go to"))
```