# Redirect to new url from flask form

Tags: python, forms, flask

I'm using flask to make a scheduler app. I have a function that will take a list of college courses from the url and schedule them. Is there any way to make a form that people could enter the classes in as opposed to using the url?

My view function:

```
@app.route('/sched/<some_list>')
def scheduleMe(some_list):
    course_list = some_list.split(',')
    my_combos = scheduler.schedule(course_list)
    return render_template("sched.html", title="Scheduler", combos=my_combos)
```

takes in a list of courses such as `BT 353,CS 135,HHS 468,BT 181,CS 146,CS 284` and returns a page with all the possible schedules for those courses.

I'm trying to make some sort of form where if a user entered the courses above it would redirect them to `www.mysite.com/sched/<courses they enter>`. I was going to use GET and then basically make a view function that was take the resulting url from the form and pull the courses out of the query.

Is there a better/ more direct way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best way to answer a question on stackoverflow. Flask does provide a [redirect option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14343812/redirecting-to-url-in-flask) to another url. Also check [url_for](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.url_for). For more on forms, you can look [here](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iii-web-forms).