# Flask redirect with same url and different host?

Tags: python, redirect, flask

I'm using flask as web server.

Currently, I have a request: `http://host-a.com/test1/?a=1&b=2` and I want to redirect to `http://host-b.com/test1/?a=1&b=2` and get the response.

Now, I have a lot of such url as `test1`, `test2` and so on. I just want to redirect the host. How to deal with it?

edited: There are many urls need to be redirected, while there are also many urls can't be redirected.

For example: `http://host-a.com/test1/?a=1&b=2` need, but `http://host-a.com/real1/?a=1&b=2` can't

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirecting to URL in Flask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14343812/redirecting-to-url-in-flask)

Comment: @YuvalPruss No, you don't understand the problem. There are many urls need to be redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So perhaps this will help you:

```
from flask import Flask, redirect
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', defaults={'path': ''})
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def catch_all(path):
    new_path = 'http://host-b.com/' + path
    return redirect(new_path, code=302)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: Let me try it~.

Comment: What I do is: 1 get the url, 2 replace the host, 3 get the cookies, 4 send get using requets and get response content.
It seems that your code should be worked. Thank you!

Comment: I don't think this method will forward the parameters a=1 & b=2

Comment: You should have a proxy like nginx and handle these redirections over there.