# Flask - How to redirect to login page if the current user is not authenticated?

Tags: python, flask

My `load_user` function is like:

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    u = None
    # user_id is represented as a json-formatted string
    try:
        user = json.loads(user_id)
        u = load_user_from_backend(user.get('user_id'), user.get('password'))
    except:
        return None
    return u
```

I want the current user to be redirected back to the `login` page when `laod_user` return a None value. How do I achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirecting to URL in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14343812/redirecting-to-url-in-flask)

Comment: Dont do `except:` it will hide bugs

Answer (score 1):

Nothing that an `if` statement can't handle. Certainly not the best approach to handle user authentication, though.

```
result = load_user(user_id)
if result is None:
    return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

Comment: It may worth turning this into a decorator for a slightly more portable but far from a comprehensive solution