# Flask: how to remove request.method == POST

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask app. On the html file, I have a text input and a submit button, to POST the text input's value to flask, and add it to a database. Works pretty good.

But if I refresh the page, the app inserts the same row for a second time, because the POST method is still set as the text input's value. How do I remove the POST method after one execution?

```
if request.method == "POST":
  caseNumber = request.form["caseNumber"]
  myCursor.execute(
     "INSERT INTO CASES VALUES ('{}', '', '', '', '')".format(caseNumber))
  myConnection.commit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual method is to return a redirection response.

The browser will always follow redirections with a GET response, so even if the user then hits F5 and accepts the "your request may be re-applied" prompt, there's no previous data to post.

Comment: How do I "return a redirection response"?

Comment: @BernardEsterhuyse Did you [search for `flask redirect`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14343957/51685)?