# Flask TypeError: The view function for '**' did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, typeerror

I am learning Flask and i started my first project using this framework. At the moment I want to save the user input to the database but I am getting a

> TypeError: The view function for 'bookingPage' did not return a valid response.

The function either returned None or ended without a return statement. I checked my function and the return statement must return the booking page in case if it is a GET request and redirect to the main page in case if it is a POST request.

I also checked other posts here regarding such error, but there are answers like "you need to add the return statement". In my case the return statement is present

Here is the code of my function:

```py
@app.route('/booking', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def bookingPage():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        firstname = request.form['firstname']
        lastname = request.form['lastname']
        phone = request.form['phone']
        email = request.form['email']
        birthdate = request.form['birthdate']
        booking_date = request.form['booking_date']
        booking_time = request.form['booking_time']
        guests_nr = request.form['guests_nr']
        notes = request.form['notes']

        reservation = Booking(CustomerFname=firstname, CustomerLname=lastname, CustomerPhone=phone, CustomerEmail=email,
                              CustomerBirthdate=birthdate, ReservationDate=booking_date, ReservationTime=booking_time,
                              NumberOfGuests=guests_nr, CustomerNotes=notes)

        try:
            db.session.add(reservation)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect('/')
        except:
            return "An error has been occurred. Please, try again later"
    else:
        return render_template('booking.html')
```

Also here is the code of the html

```html
<div class="booking-container">
    <form method="post">
        <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" required>
        <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" required>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required>
        <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number" required>
        <input type="text" name="birthdate" id="birthdate" class="form-control" placeholder="Date of Birth" required>
        <input type="text" name="booking_date" id="booking_date" class="form-control" placeholder="Reservation Date" required>
        <input type="text" name="booking_time" id="booking_time" class="form-control" placeholder="Reservation Time" required>
        <input type="text" name="guests_nr" id="guests_nr" class="form-control" placeholder="Number of Guests" required>
        <textarea name="notes" id="notes" class="form-control" placeholder="Notes"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" class="btn-submit" value="Sent">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Set a few `print` to ensure you reach the `return` statement, even if any exception should be seen in the server console if happen

Comment: Yes, I tried 'try:
            db.session.add(reservation)
            db.session.commit()
            print('try')
            return redirect('/')
        except:
            print('errr')
            return "An error has been occurred. Please, try again later"
    else:
        print('final')
        return render_template('booking.html')' and it show the print from "errr" from the exception and the print "final" from the return statement

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868143/post-then-redirect-and-methodviews is about methodviews, but the 1st answer applies also to your case. Change the redirect to `return redirect('/', code=303)`.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to add code=303, but the error didn't disappeared :(

Answer (score 0):

the issue is solved. I made a stupid mistake there:

In
def booking():
if request.method == 'POST':

must be ['POST'] instead of 'POST'